# Better antivirus for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 VPS

Tags: windows-server-2008, anti-virus, licensing

I have only one VPS with Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 and want to buy an Antivirus. I tried NOD32 but they do not give less than 5 users in business edition (I have only one server). Kaspersky may be another solution but whether should i go for Internet Security or Anti-virus?

I have few website hosted on this server and user have ability to upload .jpg, .gif, .zip files in few of the folders.

Apart from above two any other suggestions on Antivirus that works well on above configuration and available for only one user?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I always liked ClamWin.  May or may not meet your requirements though.  It doesn't scan everything all the time, so performance is better, but that might be something you need.  Interestingly enough, I see it performed horribly on an AV "roundup" test a few months ago, but the previous year it was a top performer.  Not sure about the status at this time though.  I'm pretty suspicious of those tests though.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I like AVG, and you can buy it on a per machine basis.  The only downside is that from time to time when they update their scanner it requires a machine reboot so you have to schedule those for convenient times.

Comment: AVG is good, but it is not supported in Windows Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 1):

We like Trend Worry Free (hosted on their server or yours), we can add all of our clients to one control panel and manage changes from there, no AV servers at client sites.  This may help with the single user since it can handle multiple sites.

Comment: I'm going to check that out for my local network.

Answer (score 1):

Kaspersky Internet Security is the consumer version. It doesn't support server OS's, so Windows 2008 R2's right out.

You'd be looking at their **Kaspersky Business Space Security** suite, in order to get the **Kaspersky Anti-Virus for Windows Servers** product, which supports Windows 2008 R2  Unfortunately you normally can only buy these in bundles of 10+ licenses, and will start at around £250. Kaspersky might be able to do you a deal though.

Answer (score 0):

[ESET NOD32 Antivirus](http://www.eset.com/business/small/nod32-antivirus) 4 is sold on single server basis. I just spoke with sales and have installed a trial on the one server that needs AV. Their web site is really confusing though. I thought the same thing until I called them.

So far it seems fine, though I've only been using it for a short time.